# how to elevate administrator pirivileges only when required vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, privileges

I want to make an application with self-update function.

Unfortunately, when I want to click on the button called "Update" it throws an error, with the message: "Access Denied!"

Here is the code I used:

```
Public Sub versionfileUPDATE()
    Try
        If System.IO.File.Exists(My.Settings.telepitesihely & "/seemtahelperv1downloader.exe") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(My.Settings.telepitesihely & "/seemtahelperv1downloader.exe")
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/azz6qundbe2rna1/SeeMta%20PK%20Generator%20V1.exe?dl=11"), My.Settings.telepitesihely & "/seemtahelperv1downloader.exe")
        Else
            client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/azz6qundbe2rna1/SeeMta%20PK%20Generator%20V1.exe?dl=1"), My.Settings.telepitesihely & "/seemtahelperv1downloader.exe")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

So, is there any solution to require administrator privilege, when the user clicks on the update button?

Comment: You will be unable to delete the executable file if it is currently running as it will be locked by the filesystem.  This may be why you are receiving the error.

Comment: i know,it closes the file before deleting it.

Comment: Is the code running `versionfileUPDATE()` inside `seemtahelperv1downloader.exe` or is a different program running that code?

Comment: "seemtahelperv1downloader" is another program,the program where the code is running is updated by that program,and this is the program what user uses to start the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes must be given an administrator token when they start or they never will get one at all. The only way to make it work "on demand" is you must make a 2nd program that requires administrator privlages that does the download and nothing else, you then have your program launch the 2nd program and wait for it to finish.

However, the better solution is choose a better save location that does not require administrator privileges to write to, for example you can use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the user's `LocalApplicationData` folder (for example for you that would point to somthing like `C:\Users\Ntohing_Trolll\AppData\Local`) and save and run the exe from a subfolder in there. That is what programs like Chrome do for their updating so you don't require administrative privileges to update.

Comment: A example of what? [Finding the users Application Data folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Anchor_3) or making the 2nd downloader program [always run as administrator](http://www.downloadinformer.com/2014/01/how-to-make-vbnet-application-always.html)?

Comment: In the first link you would use `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` instead of `Environment.SpecialFolder.System` for your code

Comment: an example on making the 2nd downloader program.

Comment: You are already using a 2nd program aren't you?  You said "[it closes the file before deleting it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215610/how-to-elevate-administrator-pirivileges-only-when-required-vb-net/39215657?noredirect=1#comment65769933_39215610)", I assume you are not talking about the program closing itself, because if it is closed it could not be running the code. Make that 2nd program run as administrator using the information in the 2nd link

Comment: Yes, the seemtahelperv1downloader.exe is another application(,it starts up after the download is complete,and it download the update of SeeMtaHelper.exe(this is where i run the code to download seemtahelperv1downloader))But,i need to run BOTH application with administrative privilegs,i try'd replacing the  'asInvoker with requireAdministrator or highestAvailable in the manifest file,but,when i want to Publish the application it throws an error,it says "ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator".

Comment: Okey,i have one question left how can i find a process called "seemta helper.exe(this is how Task m. show the name of it.)and indicate to user that the process run,and if user press the OK button in msgbox,then kill the process/es.